# How to get a value of <td> tag

Tags: javascript, html-target

I am getting `<td value="1414">Nishant</td>` by `event.target`. I want 1414 and as I try to get value by using `event.target.value` I am getting undefined. How can I get that value?

Comment: That is invalid HTML. `<td>` elements do not have a value. But you can still get it by using `event.target.getAttribute('value')`

Comment: `value` isn't valid attribute of `td` element. You can try `data-value` attribute and `event.target.getAttribute['data-value']`

Answer (score 1):

`td` elements don't have value. What you are looking for is to get the value of the attribute `value` of that element.

You can do this using the `getAttribute` function:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('a').getAttribute('value'));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="a" value="123">a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `data-*` in order to "save" [custom data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) on DOM node.
And then access it via `domNode.dataset.*` as a camelCase.

```js
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.value);
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-value="123">a</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

for very old browsers you can use `e.target.getAttribute("data-value")`

Comment: Important to note the `dataset` is not available in IE10  :(